# Ionic 3 Error - fullscreen and ion-refresher don't work together

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

After adding `fullscreen` to my ion-content, my `ion-refresher` is no longer visible. Changing CSS is every way possible doesn't help. I've found this post https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/10490, which seems to indicate that this is a genuine Ionic bug, but it's been almost a year and so far I couldn't find anything else on this: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/10490

Does anyone know a workaround? Or any advice will be highly appreciated.